# What's the difference between \newtheorem{remark}*{Remark} and \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}?

Tags: theorems

Does anyone know the differences between `\newtheorem{remark}*{Remark}` and `\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}`?

Comment: There are several implementations of `\newtheorem` you need to give a complete example, showing which packages you are using. `ntheorem` ? `amsthm` ? ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no widely available package with the syntax `\newtheorem{remark}*{Remark}`; I think it should be

```
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
```

There are two well known packages that provide the macro `\newtheorem*`: [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem). According to the package documentation, `\newtheorem` is for defining numbered theorem environments, whereas `\newtheorem*` is for defining theorem styles that are not to be numbered.